# Make file for multi-directory project

Tags: java, macos, makefile, javac

I am trying to do a makefile for a java project that pretty much compiles the whole project and place the compiled files in a bin directory. This is my file architectures : 
[image: file architecture]

This is my makefile at the root directory :

```
BIN=./bin/
SOURCE=./src/

all:
    cd src; make
clean:
    rm -f $(BIN)*.class
```

and this is my makefile in the src directory :

```
BIN=../bin/

sourcefiles = \
MessageMondial.class \
Bonjour.class

classfiles  = $(sourcefiles:.java=.class)

all: $(classfiles)
$(BIN)%.class: /src/%.java
    javac -d $(BIN) -classpath . $<
```

if I go in the src directory and run the make all command everything gets compiled and is putted in the bin directory like it should.

However when I run the make all command from the root directory of the project I get this error :

[image: error message]

How can I run the make all command from the root directory of the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
sourcefiles = \
MessageMondial.class \
Bonjour.class
```

should be

```
sourcefiles = \
MessageMondial.java \
Bonjour.java
```

but I would also recommend you use maven, ant, gradle or sbt instead of `make`. Make was not a tool designed for building Java projects.

Comment: Ok got maven up and running. Thank you for pointing me in the right way. However the typo in the file extension did not fix the problem.